# Sending parameters through button on rails form_tag with put method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing, put, link-to, button-to

I have two links ( could be buttons if needed ) that say accept and decline and I need to send true or false parameters to my controller action by clicking one of those links. I don't want my parameters to be visible in the url so I need to use put method. I have tried with the link_to with defined method:

```
<%= link_to 'accept', { action: 'accept_offer', accept: true }, method: :put %>
<%= link_to 'decline', { action: 'accept_offer', accept: false }, method: :put %>
```

but my params are still visible.

I've tried using button_to but then my parameters are not passed.
What is the best way to determine which option has been chosen (accept or decline) without showing parameters in url?

my route has be defined like this:

```
put 'offers', to: 'offers#accept_offer'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'll recommend to make a form instead of link_to and pass params in name. Use a form and POST the information.This might require additional code in source pages, but should not require logic changes in the target pages.

```
<% form_for @offer, :url => {:action => 'accept_offer'} do |f|%>
  <%= submit_tag "", :value => "Accept", :name => "accept" %>
  <%= submit_tag "", :value => "Decline", :name => "decline"  %>
<% end %>
```

in your action you'll get  params[:accept] or params[:decline] based on the link you clicked.

Edited to include commas and spaces with keyword arguments on submit tag.]

Comment: Because I needed to just pass parameters to controller action in order to determine action flow, I've managed to use your suggestion with submit_tag inside form_tag with my action and put method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start with just the conventional routes:

```
resources :offers
```

Then lets use button_to to create a discrete form:

```
<%= button_to 'accept', @offer, method: :patch, params: { "offer[accept]" =>  true } %>
<%= button_to 'decline', @offer, method: :patch, params: { "offer[accept]" => false } %>
```

The `params` option creates hidden inputs inside the form.

Then make sure you whitelist the correct attribute:

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])

    if @offer.update(offer_params)
      redirect_to @offer, success: 'Offer updated'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def offer_params
     params.require(:offer).permit(:accept, :foo, :bar)
  end
end
```

If you need to have separate logic from the regular update then create two additional verbs:

```
resources :offers do
  member do
    patch :accept
    patch :decline
  end
end
```

---

```
<%= button_to 'accept', accept_offer_path(@offer), method: :patch %>
<%= button_to 'decline', decline_offer_path(@offer), method: :patch %>
```

This keeps your API restful and decriptive.